# Dynamically render injected vue components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I'm currently working on a third party app, using Vue to render components.

The third party application loads the component dynamically after Vue app is intialized and mounted. As a result, I could only see the HTML of the component, but not actually the template that is inteded to be rendered. Meaning, I could see something like `<my-component></my-component>` when I inspect, but not the template of the `myComponent`.

Here is an example of the challenge I'm mentioning about https://jsfiddle.net/EmeraldCodeNinja/31jkmzgc/12/. In this example, you will find a button, clicking on which appends vue component to the DOM using JavaScript.

Please suggest a way to make this work, so I can render dynamically added component.

Note: The intention is not to make the JSFiddle work, it is just an example simulating the challenge I'm facing. My intention is to make the dynamically added vue-component to render.

Posting the same HTML and JS from the JSFiddle

HTML

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.37/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <sample-button></sample-button>
  <div id="new-button-wrap"></div>
</div>

<script id="sample-button" type="text/html">
    <button @click="addNew">Add Another Sample Button</button>
</script>
```

JS

```
const app = Vue.createApp();

app.component('sample-button', {
    template: '#sample-button',
  setup() {
    const addNew = function() {
      var div = document.createElement('div');
      var sampleBtn = document.createElement('sample-button');
      div.textContent = 'here a button should appear, but instead a tag is appearing'
      div.appendChild(sampleBtn)
        document.querySelector('#new-button-wrap').appendChild(div)
    }
    return {
        addNew
    }
  }
})

app.mount('#app');
```

Comment: Can you post the code you have an issue with in the question rather than an external link

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically adding different components in Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50418651/dynamically-adding-different-components-in-vue)

Comment: No @Duannx. The component must be added dynamically, without Vue updating any params. In my case a thirdparty script updates HTML of a component, injecting a new component into an initialized Vue App.

Comment: In your case, I think you should use [custom elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements) Because Vue can not understand HTML that comes from the outside of the Vue app. [See more](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/web-components.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Vue instance in run-time using `createApp` and `mount` methods to append it to the DOM.

```
createApp({
      template: "<button id=`button`>I'm a button!</button>",
}).mount(document.getElementById("button-container"));
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-wind-n27i8z?file=/src/App.vue) is the CodeSandbox link